# ArcGIS server extension: Marshal.ReleaseComObject() or not?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects

The ServerSimpleImageServiceRESTSOE example uses Marshal.ReleaseComObject(). The other examples seem to not use this.

When should I use Marshal.ReleaseComObject()?

As I understand if I am not using ReleaseComObject the garbage collector deletes the COM object when it finds appropriate. Since the COM objects not necessarily consume any memory this may be almost never.

Could keeping workspace, rasters etc open as COM objects eventually lead to crashes? If so will there be thrown an exception that explains that the system is running out of filehandles etc?

On the other hand "Calling ReleaseComObject affects all managed references to a COM object in the current process.".
May not this cause problems since several instances of the server may run in the same process?

Answer (score 1):

Who said 'COM objects don't consume memory'? It may not be much but they do have at least *a reference* in memory... If you've only got 4GB to play with sometimes you need to be careful of even the little things.

Most Esri objects are cleaned up nicely by the garbage collector, with cursors being a noticeable exception, workspaces and modified feature classes too should be released properly to release locks but not so much with features, geometry objects etc..

I have noticed when memory usage starts to creep up sometimes the GC cleans up something that isn't done with yet leading to 'Out of memory' error which means *'the object you want to use is no longer in memory, it's been cleaned up'* and not *'you've used up all your RAM'* as you would think it means.

To avoid crashing due to the 'out of memory' problem try calling the [GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever you truly get rid of something big, flush a cursor or re-instantiate something (overwrite an object variable); but how can you tell what's 'big'? Experience I guess.. Workspaces are big, features are not but I know of no rule to determine *bigness* in a general sense. On the upside, repeated calls to [GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) artificially age earlier objects making them less susceptible to light collection unless they're released via marshal or re-instantiated.

So, yes, keeping and not releasing workspaces etc. is utimately a bad idea as you can maintain locks that aren't required for operations that were complete ages ago and jamming up your allowed memory space with objects that aren't going to be used again (most likely) and because they're older they are less likely to be removed by GC leaving only the 'in use' objects, the newest and most valuable to the current process, on the headsmans' block - a true recipie for disaster the longer and harder a process is pushed.